# Target currently clicked instance of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple instances of a button element:

```
<div id="openambiance" class="openclose leftside"></div>
<div id="opendesign" class="openclose rightside"></div>
<div id="openperform" class="openclose leftside"></div>
```

They carry different ID's, as clicking on each of them opens different panel. I would like currently open panel to switch its open/close button background, as per definition in .openclose-active. Reality however is, they are all getting affected. My initial code looked like this and I quickly realised why they are all getting affected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openambiance").click(function(e){
        $("#hiddenambiance").slideToggle(600,"easeInOutQuint");
        $(".openclose").toggleClass("openclose-active");
    });
});
```

So I tried targeting specific elements:

```
$(this).find(".openclose").toggleClass( "openclose-active" );
```

That failed, so I went on to .siblings, .next and .parent, but with no luck. They are still either all switched or only previous instances get switched. I'm lost :(

Comment: _"I have multiple instances of a button element"_ They don't look like buttons to me.

Comment: You're not looking for a descendent of your clicked element, but the element itself. Try $(this) without the .find() and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the element you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openambiance").click(function(e){
        $("#hiddenambiance").slideToggle(600,"easeInOutQuint");
        $(this).toggleClass("openclose-active openclose");
    });
});
```

You are clicking on the button which has the class `openclose`, so you need to toggle the class for `this` element not for any of its descendants

Comment: He can go about his business. Move along.

Comment: Goddamn it, that should have came into my mind first. Thanks a bunch, the day is saved!